# Classifier which minimizes inaccuracy

Tags: machine-learning, classification, mathematical-statistics

I recently interviewed for a machine learning job which involved very mathematically rigorous questions. This is one of them, which I'm still very confused about.

*Question*: Given a data generating distribution $\mathbb{P}(x,y)$ and a classifier $f(x)$, where $x$ is the observation and $y$ is the label, prove that the **inaccuracy** given by:

$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}(f(x) \neq y)]$$

is minimized by the classifier:
$$f^*(x) = \text{sign}\big(\mathbb{P}(y|x) - \frac{1}{2}\big)$$

where $\mathbb{1}(a \neq b)$ is $1$ when $a \neq b$ and $0$ otherwise, and $\text{sign}(a)$ gives the arithmetic sign of $a$, that is $+1$ or $-1$.

---

Now I have multiple concerns about this question which really confuse me:

1. What is the meaning of this statement? What does it say on an *intuitive* level?
2. What information does it give us about the classifier? Can this information be used to design a "practically good" classifier for the problem which can be learned from data?
3. What is the use of this result? How does it relate to, say, designing a logistic regression classifier? I ask about logistic regression because there also we threshold our predicted probability at $0.5$.

Comment: I think there are many ways to attack this. Just so I stay in my comfort zone I would say that minimising the inaccuracy is the same as maximising the accuracy and then go ahead and just browbeat the Naive Bayes on them. Tim's answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296014) and Antoine's answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191924) give the necessary background. (Side-note: what kind of job was that? Was it about algorithmic trading?)

Comment: No, it was a research job. The work involves experimenting with new ML algorithms and writing papers. Given that the interviewers were researchers themselves, I guess it makes sense that the interview was so mathematical.

Comment: Fair enough. I hope you get the position! (If you want the position)

Comment: Haha, thanks! Yes, I do want the position and am waiting for their decision. Fingers crossed! :)

Answer (score 3):

To archive optimal accuracy (minimal inaccuracy) you would assign a label A to x whenever P(y|x) > 0.5 and label B whenever P(y|x) < 0.5.

In other words, P(y|x) together with threshold 0.5 is the optimal Bayes classifier.

This is equivalent to assign labels based on the sign P(y|x) - 0.5, as you simply project the probabilities of P(y|x) in [0, 1] to the interval [-0.5, +0.5]. The decision boundary in probability space, 0.5, becomes 0 in the projected space and thus you can check whether a sample lies on either side of the decision boundary by checking the sign of P(y|x) - 0.5.

I'm sure you can formulate this a lot more mathematically, but this is the intuition.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. One more thing that was really confusing to me was the $\mathbb{P}(y|x)$. Why is this a probability between [0, 1]? I thought it should be *exactly* 0 or 1? Is the true label $\mathbb{P}(y|x)$ probabilistic because of noise in the data collection process?

Comment: Not necessarily. For example, assume y $\in$ {0, 1} and x is a real number. The x of samples with label 0 could follow a normal distribution with mean 0 and sd 1 (D1), while the x of samples with label 1 could follow a second normal distribution of mean 1 and sd 1 (D2). What P(y|x) actually tells you is the probability that x was drawn from say D1 as opposed to D2. However, both D1 and D2 overlap at the upper and lower tails, so there is always a degree on uncertainty. The optimal decision boundary would be the x-value where the curves of D1 and D2 intersect.